# Using OOP classes for modelling a "variable tree"

Tags: c++, oop

I'm currently working on a helper tool for Embedded projects.

Assuming I have a .elf file as an image of the embedded software (yes, I know a elf file may contain much more information). A .elf file is already linked so all the global (and static) symbols have fixed addresses.

In my "helper tool" I'm trying to use classes for modelling the symbol structure and their relations. Well, I'm only interested in global variables, no classes or functions or internal variables.
I'm using C++, but the problem is not the syntax but the related classed, so I guess I can use an abstract description here.

What I'm trying is to write a set of classes which can be used to describe all the global variables in my .elf file and their relations.

Assuming the topmost class, "globalSymbol".
A "globalSymbol" just has one member, its address.

```
globalSymbol
============
- int address
```

But this information alone is not enough to describe our symbol and it doesn't make sense so initiate an instance of this class, so I prefer making globalSymbol an abstract class. 
However, I can think of three classes to inherit from globalSymbol, namely the classes "structure", "array" and just a plain "variable".
In my model, these classes look like:

```
variable
=========
- int size (of the datatype in bytes)
- bool isSigned

structure
==========
- std::vector"Member" (I use this piece of C++ for showing that a structure can have several "Members". Unfortunately, the forum software doesn't like <> tags)

array
======
- int size (of the datatype in bytes)
- bool isSigned
- int multiplicity (actual size of the array)
```

But, after thinking about it, I feel this model is not capable of describing my global variables.
First problem is the structure class. This may work if a structure can only have members of an basic integer type. Then the "Member class" just needs size and signedness like a variable, and its offset within the structure for determining the members address.
But a structure member may itself be a structure, or an array.

So I thought of replacing the std::vector"Member" by std::vector"globalSymbol". I have already three classes, why not using them instead of writing a "Member class"?
Well, because the structure class already has its address. But a member has an offset within the structure. I'm not sure on this...

The second problem is the array class. What if I have an array of structures? How could this be modelled with my classes? On this topic, I'm completely lost.

Well, I hope I did a sufficient description of what I want to do. If not, please ask and I'm trying to provide the necessary information.
In one sentence, I'm trying to write classes for modelling global variables and their relationships in a (embedded-) C program.

Comment: It sounds like you want a full type system, as well as a simple list of symbols of that type (and their addresses). Try modelling the type explicitly, and worry about symbol addresses and instances later.

Comment: I suggest using containers for the different memory spaces and not base classes.  A global variable may be in a different container than a static variable.

Comment: @ Useless: That doesn't meet my requirement. The tool should be universal, it should be able to handle types (structures and arrays) it (or I) does not know about yet.

Comment: @ Thomas Matthews: If a global variable is static or not does not make any difference to me - its address is known after linking. But what does matter are addresses of single structure members or array elements. Thats why I try to model this - if I know the address of an structure and I know the offset of the members, I know the member's address.